# Is my code running in a web role or a web site?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I'm moving the deployment of a web app from an Azure Website into a Web Role in a Cloud Service.

Part of the migration has involved reserving some local storage in the role config and changing interactions with the local file-system to use the following mantra to find a path that is good for writing to:

```
LocalResource tempStorageResource = RoleEnvironment
                                       .GetLocalResource("SomeRoleStorage");
var targetFolderPath = tempStorageResource.RootPath;
```

However, I'd like to keep things working in the WebSite instance. I'm going to write a path provider that abstracts the actual location away. Part of implementing this will require detecting whether I'm running locally/in the debugger, but I also need to know whether the running code is running under a WebSite or a WebRole. How can I do this?

```
public class AzurePathProvider : ILocalStoragePathProvider
{
    public string GetStoragePath(string key)
    {
        var isWebRole = //????;
        if(isWebRole)
        {
            LocalResource tempStorageResource = 
                RoleEnvironment
                    .GetLocalResource(key);
            return tempStorageResource.RootPath;
        }
        else
        {
            return "/some/other/storage/location";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest thing be to just add a flag into the `web.config`?

Comment: @James: Yes, that would work.

Comment: Alternatively you could check for a specific environment variable e.g. `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME` - only problem with this would be making sure the same variable is set in your local environment.

Comment: ...however, these alternative methods represent an extra maintenance hazard, especially to anyone making new deployments later.

Comment: Check for RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable which will only be true if the code is running as Cloud Service.

Comment: @GauravMantri That looks like an answer to me...

Comment: @GauravMantri according to the MSDN [RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.isavailable.aspx) is true if the service is running *on* Azure (it doesn't mention anything about it being a Cloud service or not). Also, would this work if it's run local? From the looks of it the OP needs this to work under the debugger, you may also need to check [IsEnumlated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.isemulated.aspx) (if running under the local emulator).

Comment: It will only be true if the code is running as Cloud Service and not as website. Just checking IsEmulated will not work. First you have to check if IsAvailable is true and then check for IsEmulated.

Comment: Checking that the RoleEnvironment is available is perfectly satisfactory to me because if it is, it's able to give me the paths I need. At the end of the day, that's all I'm after.

Comment: @GauravMantri that would suggest that the documentation is either out of date or misleading. The fact that `RoleEnvironment` is available *at all* in a website is confusing to start with really. Perhaps `AppEnvironment` with a `Type` property would have been a nicer API :)

Comment: @James I would say the issue is with documentation. I just created a website and added necessary references. I checked for RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable there and it is coming as false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for [`RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.isavailable.aspx) to decide if the code is running in Cloud Service or not. It will always be `true` when your code is running in Cloud Service otherwise it will be `false`.

Furthermore to detect if the code is running in compute emulator, you can check for [`RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.isemulated.aspx) along with `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable`.